# Starting thrift server in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-thriftserver

Can anyone help me with starting spark thrift server? I am running my script in standalone mode and I want to fetch data in my business intelligence tool.

In order to do that I need to start thrift server. I tried running shell script:

```
$SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-thriftserver.sh
```

but I get an error:

> error "ps unknown option --0"

Comment: Provide more debug info, start server with `bash -x sbin/start-thriftserver.sh` and attach log to the question.

Comment: --ps: unknown option -- o (NewLine)Try `ps --help' for more information.
starting org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2, logging to /e/Development/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/logs/spark--org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2-1-TEAMTAPPS.out  After this below line keeps up repeating ps: unknown option -- o 
Try `ps --help' for more information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36593446/failed-to-start-master-for-spark-in-windows

Comment: @mariusz ...the link provides solution to start master but i want to start thrift server.

Comment: Yes, but this applies to all server scripts, spark-thriftserver is one of them.

Comment: @Mariusz.. I have called the thrift server class directly form cmd as: `E:\Development\spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\bin>spark-class org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2` but throwing error :`16/11/22 16:29:40 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration`

Comment: OK, I found a solution that should work in your environment and summarized discussion in the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `sbin/` scripts work fine under linux, but they are not prepared to run in Windows (see [Failed to start master for Spark in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36593446/failed-to-start-master-for-spark-in-windows)). But spark thriftserver can be start in foreground independent from OS using command:

```
java -cp conf/:jars/* org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit --class org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2 spark-internal
```

Then you can test connection using beeline supplied with spark:

```
$ ./bin/beeline -u jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
Connecting to jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
16/11/22 13:09:57 INFO Utils: Supplied authorities: localhost:10000
16/11/22 13:09:57 INFO Utils: Resolved authority: localhost:10000
16/11/22 13:09:57 INFO HiveConnection: Will try to open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
Connected to: Spark SQL (version 2.0.1)
Driver: Hive JDBC (version 1.2.1.spark2)
Transaction isolation: TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ
Beeline version 1.2.1.spark2 by Apache Hive
0: jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000> show databases;
+---------------+--+
| databaseName  |
+---------------+--+
| default       |
| elo           |
+---------------+--+
2 rows selected (0,26 seconds)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mariusz. Its a great relief that now i am able to start thrift server.

Comment: Hi, I get INFO  ThriftCLIService:98 - Starting ThriftBinaryCLIService on port 10000 with 5...500 worker threads and it hangs there forever. Do you know why?

Answer (score 9):

In Spark 2.2.1

```
cd %SPARK_HOME%\bin
spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit --class org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2 spark-internal
```

this started the spark thrift server in windows.
In another terminal run the below beeline command to open a jdbc connection

```
cd %SPARK_HOME%\bin
beeline -u jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000
```

Comment: Hi, I get INFO  ThriftCLIService:98 - Starting ThriftBinaryCLIService on port 10000 with 5...500 worker threads. and it hangs there. Do you know why?

Comment: Just to help others... we need t have the right version of winutils in place.