# Connect PowerBI Desktop with Apache Spark local machine installation

Tags: apache-spark, powerbi-desktop

Can someone guide me how to connect PBI Desktop to APACHE SPARK installed on a local windows machine? What should be the server details I should pass?

I have read thrift connections are very slow so would want to avoid them unless they are the only choice.

Edit -
Based on the suggestion, I tried to set up thrift connection following the below link - medium.com/@waqasrafiq327/… . Mine is a windows installation. Given paths seems to be for linux? I cant see a hive-site.xml file under /spark/conf folder. I also dont see a /apachehive/conf folder in my spark installtion. My spark installation is the latest version of spark release available. Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the thrift server as it is required if you want to connect via ODBC or JDBC. This is the only way to connect from Power BI to Apache Spark.

Comment: Hi. I tried to set it up based on the link - https://medium.com/@waqasrafiq327/connect-powerbi-with-spark-9d52071047de  . Mine is a windows installation. Given paths seems to be for linux? I cant see a hive-site.xml file under /spark/conf folder. I also dont see a /apachehive/conf folder in my spark installtion. My spark installation is the latest version of spark release available. Please guide.

Comment: Any suggestions pls?

Comment: I am not a Spark engineer, I just know what is required from a Power BI perspective. I suggest going through the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40653248/starting-thrift-server-in-spark and maybe closing this question and opening a new one on the apache-spark tag purely for configuring spark and spark thrift on Windows.

Comment: I'm ok to do that. Don't see the option to close the question.