# Using RStudio-sparklyr to connect to local Spark provided by IntelliJ

Tags: apache-spark, intellij-idea, rstudio, sparklyr

Good morning,
it maybe sounds like a stupid question, but I would like to access a temporary table in Spark by RStudio. I don't have any Spark cluster, and I only run everything local on my PC.
When I start Spark through IntelliJ, the instance is running fine:

```
    17/11/11 10:11:33 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 59505.
17/11/11 10:11:33 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
17/11/11 10:11:33 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
17/11/11 10:11:33 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
17/11/11 10:11:33 INFO BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
17/11/11 10:11:33 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at C:\Users\stephan\AppData\Local\Temp\blockmgr-7ca4e8fb-9456-4063-bc6d-39324d7dad4c
17/11/11 10:11:33 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 898.5 MB
17/11/11 10:11:33 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
17/11/11 10:11:33 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
17/11/11 10:11:34 INFO SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://172.25.240.1:4040
17/11/11 10:11:34 INFO Executor: Starting executor ID driver on host localhost
17/11/11 10:11:34 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 59516.
17/11/11 10:11:34 INFO NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on 172.25.240.1:59516
```

But I am not sure about the port, I have to choose in RStudio/sparklyr:

```
sc <- spark_connect(master = "spark://localhost:7077", spark_home = "C://Users//stephan//Downloads//spark//spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7", version = "2.2.0")
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file 'C:\Users\stephan\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp61Ejow\file2fa024ce51af_spark.log': Permission denied
```

I tried different ports, like 59516, 4040, ... but all led to the same result. The permission denied message I guess can be ignored due that the file is written fine:

```
17/11/11 01:07:30 WARN StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master localhost:7077
```

Can please anyone assist me, how I can establish a connection between a local running Spark and RStudio, but without that RStudio is running another Spark instance?

Thanks
Stephan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running standalone Spark cluster is not the same thing as running Spark in `local` mode in your IDE, which is likely the case here. `local` mode doesn't create any persistent services.

To run your own "pseudodistributed" cluster:

- Download Spark binaries.
- Start Spark master using `$SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-master.sh` script.
- Start Spark worker using `$SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-slave.sh` script and passing master url.

To be able to share tables you'll also need a proper metastore (not Derby).

Comment: I see. That's too bad :(
I followed this thread about running it local: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36593446/failed-to-start-master-for-spark-in-windows and changed my config to "spark://172.25.240.1:7077".
When I run my application now, it is getting contacted, however, the StreamingContext is not working anymore. It is executed by streamingContext.start() and streamingContext.awaitTermination(). As long as I run this in Intellij, it is catching the stream. 
Btw. the stream actually is just a local socket stream I generated by myself