# Run spark from source code on Windows - no such file or directory error

Tags: apache-spark

I would like to run Spark from source code on my Windows machine. I did the following steps:

1. git clone https://github.com/apache/spark
2. Added the SPARK_HOME variable into the user variables.
3. Added %SPARK_HOME%\bin to the PATH variable.
4. ./build/mvn -DskipTests clean package
5. ./bin/spark-shell

The last command returns the following error:
[image]

What should I do to fix the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, refer to the link below for the solution. The top voted answer gave me the working script for this problem.
: [Failed to start master for Spark in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36593446/failed-to-start-master-for-spark-in-windows)

The reason is that spark launch scripts do not support Windows. The spark documentation (https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/spark-standalone.html) insists you to start the master and workers manually if you are a Windows user. So you need to first run the master and then run spark-shell.