Apache Spark using scala ide and java
C:\spark>spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
The system cannot find the path specified.
i tried it by setting the path and im expecting to solve the error maybe the path had not been configured prpoperly or i dont know what.give me a clear explanation to solve this error

Check if this can help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36593446/failed-to-start-master-for-spark-in-windows

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
